# how to deal with Memo fields listed in a SELECT query, in foxpro 9?

Tags: select, foxpro, visual-foxpro

i have a query where i need to use the DISTINCT keyword, the issue is that a field i have in the select is of type MEMO (needs to be so because of its large content...).

```
SELECT distinct customerid, commentdate, commenttext....
```

is not accepted in FOXPRO 9 because commenttext field is f type Memo !
any idea?

Comment: As Tamar mentioned, what is the real goal of "distinct" that you want.  Can you please try to post the entire query you are looking for.  It may help for a final solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, depending on your needs:

1) Omit the memo field from the query.
2) Use an expression to convert the memo field to character. For example, LEFT(commenttext,254).

Are you really trying to apply distinct to the memo field, as well? What's your actual goal here?

Tamar

Comment: not trying to have distinct comments, but i don't know how to separate this field from the rest of the fields i'm trying to get distinct values, like dates, customerid , and other stuff...

Comment: Just leave the memo field out of the query entirely in that case. After all, once you have the rest distinct, using a particular memo field wouldn't be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the memo field in the `SELECT` statement in a function such as `ALLTRIM`.

`SELECT distinct customerid, commentdate, ALLTRIM(commenttext)....`

Comment: tried that, it says "string too long to contain"...i think i'm going to truncate...after all it's just a comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use something like PHDBase which is a text search indexer for Visual Foxpro. It allows character columns and memo fields to be indexed and searchable. And it's incredibly fast.